# Virtualizing Debian 9.8 on Virtualbox

Tags: debian, virtualbox

I am trying to virtualize Debian 9.8 on Virtualbox 6.0 by creating a new Virtual Machine type linux Debian, adding the Debian.iso file but I get the message:

> FATAL: No booteable medium found! System halted

I have downloaded the debian iso file from: https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-dvd/
But I don´t know what happens, if I try with Ubuntu, OpenSuse, Fedora, everything goes ok.

PD: I tryed with VMWare and the error message is the same...

Can any one help me please?

Answer (score 2):

I scrolled to the bottom of the link you posted and downloaded this file: "debian-9.9.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso". If you use this file it should work. If it doesn't your virtual optical drive is empty and you need to add the iso file to it like so:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Et55Y.png)

Comment: I have used the "debian-9.9....DVD-3.iso" file now I am gonna try with "1.iso" and see what happens thank you!

Comment: @DavidDavila Your welcome, let me know if you still have trouble.

Comment: Nothing bro, the same error, I have no problem with openSuse, Ubuntu, Fedora, CentOs, is just Debian, I gonna use openSuse. Thank you for your reply.